# Time validation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form which takes start time and end time of an event in 12H format. I need to validate it if end time is greater than start time it shows an error like "End time should be greater than start time". However i have managed it mostly but problem occurs if user puts start time "12:30 PM" and end time "01:00 PM" (which is a valid time) it still shows the error. How do i manage this in client side validation?? I am using javascript on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i end up with this code:

```
var s = new Date("03/02/2012 12:30 pm");
var e = new Date("03/02/2012 01:00 pm");
if( s.getTime() < e.getTime() )
{
    document.write('Valid Time');
}
else
{
    document.write('Invalid Time');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it can be done by pure JS.

```
var s = "12:30 pm";
var e = "01:00 pm";
var base = "Wed, 09 Aug 1995 ";
var start_d = Date.parse(base+s.substr(0, 5)+":00"+s.substr(5));
var end_d = Date.parse(base+e.substr(0, 5)+":00"+e.substr(5));

if(start_d<end_d){
 // range is valid;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code but when i print the values of start_d and end_d in console it shows 'NaN' for both.

Comment: @ShayanHusaini, Thats because I have used `substr(6)`. Now I have updated to `substr(5)`. If you echo start_d it'll show `807949800000`

Comment: yeah now i have got the values but it still consider start_d greater than end_d. Which is not the case here

Comment: What is your browser? see http://ideone.com/ZCaHm it does **NOT** consider `start_d` is greater than `end_d`.

Comment: I am using firefox 10.0.2 and i need a browser compatible solution. I have posted the final code please review it and let me know if it has any defect. And thanx for your help

Comment: `Date.parse` is implemented from JavaScript 1.0. So it's available in every modern and old browser. Firefox uses spidermonkey us engine. How you are testing in Firefox? see how it works on spidermonkey http://ideone.com/CpDRt

Comment: i have tested your code in w3schools try it yourself. and it sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) console in your firefox. In my Firefox 10.0.2 I see start_d is always smaller than end_d.